# Inject javascript in standerd lightning detail page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I had created a custom lightning component to send email(customized based on requirement) and I added the component in page.

But my component is not loaded when page is loaded instead of it is showing text box and button(named as add) once i click the text box or button then only my component is loading.(refer below Image)

[image]

Im trying to add some `js` to trigger the add button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at there is the standard feed publisher component. You cannot manipulate it with JavaScript; Locker Service prohibits you from reaching across namespaces in your JavaScript code.

You can change the suite of Quick Actions shown in the default publisher component by editing the Case Page Layout's Lightning and Mobile Quick Actions section to remove those items you don't desire. Then, place your custom component on the page canvas - it looks like it has *not* been placed, by your screenshot.